# Redirect user when he "likes" a facebook page tab

Tags: php, facebook

How is it possible to redirect the user to another page when he likes a page tab?

I followed this tutorial : 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

All is working perfectly but i need to display another page if he likes the page tab.
Same problem if he unlikes the page. The previous page should reappear....

this is the code i found but not working...

```
<?php
require 'php-sdk/src/facebook.php';
?>

<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>


    </head>
    <body>
            you don't like yet

    </body>

    <script>
        FB.api(pageId +  '/likes', 'post' ,function(response) {


            location.href = 'youlike.php';

        });
    </script>
</html>
```

I hope i'm clear enough.

If you want to test yourself : http://www.facebook.com/Luthe131
the page tab is test app

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using php sdk, Lets do it by php, you dont need to use FB.api() to check your own page is liked or not.here is how to do it,

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => APP_ID,
      'secret' => APP_SECRET,
      'cookie' => true,
    ));

    $signedRequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
    $liked = $signedRequest["page"]["liked"];
```

Now if the user liked the page, **$liked** will be **1**,
now,

```
`if($liked){
    header("Location:youlike.php");
 }else{
 echo "you didnt like";
 }`
```

oh, and facebook refreshes the app when like button is triggered. so, value of $liked will change accordingly.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for , perfect and well explained dude !